# How to search a specific sequence in BAM files for 10X experiment

Tags: rna-seq, scrnaseq, 10x-genomics

I have to search a specific sequence in a set of cells (> 1k cells) from a single-cell experiment done with [10X genomics](https://www.10xgenomics.com/).

As input file I have a single bam file, and 24 fastqs, therefore each file contains information about several cells. How can I search for a specific sequence and underpin which single cells have it?

I should be able to search for a specific sequence in a bam using samtools, etc. But the issue here is how to demultiplex the data from different cells to understand which cell provide the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bam file has bam tags which say what reads belong to what cells.

https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/output/bam